# Why does setState cause 2 rerenders here?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

```js
export const Component = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);

    const renderCount = useRef<number>(0);
    renderCount.current =  renderCount.current + 1;

    return (<>
        <div>{`Rendered ${renderCount.current} times`}</div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{`Clicked ${renderCount.current} times`}</button>
    </>);
}
```

I'd expect for clicking the button to cause one rerender, because the value of `count` updates, and the UI has to rebuild itself. But it seems to cause two rerenders with every change. How/why is this happening?

Comment: Are you wrapping your app with `StrictMode`?

Comment: Yes, I am. Just tested, that's the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wrapping your app with `<StrictMode>`, it will always render twice.

According to docs, this is an intentional feature for the development mode of React, since `<StrictMode>` aims to help you optimize your code and tries to find any issues that your hooks might cause.